# How to create interface for a function which creates a nested element structure in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript. I am implementing a previously created function using javascript. The function takes in an object. Which have following properties

- `tag`: which will be a `string`.
- `children`: which is array of the same interface(i.e `ceProps` as shown below);
- `style`: which will be object containing styles like (`color`, `fontSize` etc.)
- Any other keys could be added to this object.(Like `innerHTML`, `src` etc.)

Here is by code.

```
interface Style { 
    [key : string ]: string;
}

interface ceProps {
    tag: string;
    style?: Style;
    children?: ceProps[];
    [key : string]: string;
}

const ce = ({tag, children, style, ...rest } : ceProps) => {
    const element = document.createElement(tag);

    //Adding properties
    for(let prop in rest){
        element[prop] = rest[prop];
    }

    //Adding children
    if(children){
        for(let child of children){
            element.appendChild(ce(child))     
        }
    }

    //Adding styles
    if(style){
        for(let prop in style){
            element.style[prop] = style[prop];
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

It shows error on the `style` and `children`

> Property `'style'` of type `'Style | undefined'` is not assignable to string index type `'string'`.ts(2411)
>
> Property `'children'` of type `'ceProps[] | undefined'` is not assignable to string index type `'string'`.ts(2411)

There is one more error one the line `element[prop] = rest[prop];` and same error on `element.style[prop] = style[prop];`

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'HTMLElement'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'HTMLElement'

Kindly explain each problem and its fix.

Comment: __Any other keys could be added to this object__ what do you mean by that? You can not have `[key : string]: string;` along with other properties in `csProps` interface

Comment: @Plochie Some keys like `tag` is essential. `children` and `style` is optional. And any other key can also be added.

Comment: When you say `[key : string]: string;` in `csProps`, it means interface properties keys should be string and value should be string, but this is conflict for `style` and `children` properties as they are not of type string. I hope I am making sense. your problem is `[key : string]: string;` statement.

Comment: @Plochie Thanks. I got it. Using `[key : string]: any;` removes the error. What about the second error?

Comment: Can edit the question so that i can post the answer?

Comment: @Plochie I think you should answer both the questions. It will help new users. You can edit..

Comment: TypeScript doesn't really support [objects with "default" or "exceptional" index signatures](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867), so any answer is going to be a workaround or fairly complicated.  If you want a *generic* type `type CeProps<K extends string> = ...` where `K` is a union of the added keys, and where `ce` becomes a generic function like `ce<K extends string>(p: CeProps<K>)` you can get it to work.  Do you want that as an answer or does the existing answer suffice for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Answering Your Questions

#### Assignability with index properties

Yes, interfaces will not let you define both a string-index property, and properties using specific strings that are defined differently. You can get around this using an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type ceProps =
    & {
        tag: string;
        style?: Style;
        children?: ceProps[];
    }
    & {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
```

This tells Typescript that `tag` will always be there and always be a string, `style` may or may not be there, but will be a `Style` when it is there, and `children` may or may not be there, but will be a `ceProps[]` when it is there. Any other property may also exist, and will always be a string.

#### Indexing `HTMLElement`

The problem is that you specified that `ceProps` could include any string as a property, but `HTMLElement` does not have any string ever as a property, it has particular properties defined for it.

You can escape out of Typescript’s checking here by casting `element` as `any`, or `element.style` as `any`, like so:

```
    //Adding properties
    for (const prop in rest) {
        (element as any)[prop] = rest[prop];
    }
```

```
    if (style) {
        for (const prop in style) {
            (element.style as any)[prop] = style[prop];
        }
    }
```

However, **this is not type-safe**. Nothing is checking that the properties in your `ceProps` is actually a property that the element you created can have or use. HTML is pretty forgiving—most of the time the property will just be silently ignored—but that can be even more hair-pulling than a crash is, because you’ll have no indication what’s wrong.

In general, you should be **extremely cautious about using `any`.** Sometimes you have to, but it should always make you uncomfortable.

### Improving the Type Safety

This will let you compile your existing code as Typescript, and it will provide at least a little bit of type-safety. Typescript can do much, much better though.

#### `CSSStyleDeclaration`

The `lib.dom.d.ts` file that comes with Typescript has loads of definitions for all kinds of things in HTML and native Javascript. One of them is `CSSStyleDeclaration`, a type used for styling HTML elements. Use this instead of your own `Style` declaration:

```
type ceProps =
    & {
        tag: string;
        style?: CSSStyleDeclaration;
        children?: ceProps[];
    }
    & {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
```

When you do this, you no longer need to cast `element.style` with `(element.style as any)`—you can just use this:

```
    //Adding styles
    if (style) {
        for (const prop in style) {
            element.style[prop] = style[prop];
        }
    }
```

This works because now Typescript knows that your `style` is the same kind of object as `element.style`, so this will work out correctly. As a bonus, now when you create your `ceProps` in the first place, you’ll get an error if you use a bad property—win-win.

#### Generic Types

The definition of `ceProps` will allow you to define a structure that will work with `ce` to create any element. But a potentially better solution here is to make this generic. That way we can track which tag is associated with a particular instance of `ceProps`.

```
type CeProps<Tag extends string = string> =
    & {
        tag: Tag;
        style?: CSSStyleDeclaration;
        children?: CeProps[];
    }
    & {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
```

(I renamed `ceProps` to `CeProps` to be more in-line with typical Typescript naming style, though of course your project is welcome to use its own style.)

The angle brackets indicate generic type parameters, here `Tag`. Having `Tag extends string` means that `Tag` is *constrained* to be a string—something like `CeProps<number>` will be an error. The `= string` part is a default parameter—if we write `CeProps` without angle brackets, we mean `CeProps<string>`, that is, any string.

The advantage of this is that Typescript supports [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), which extend string. So you could use `CeProps<"a">`, and then we would know that `tag` is not just any string, but `"a"` specifically.

So then we have the ability to indicate what tag we’re talking about. For example:

```
const props: CeProps<"a"> = { tag: "a", href: "test" };
```

If you were to write `tag: "b"` here, you would get an error—Typescript will require that this be an `"a"`. You could write a function that takes only a specific `CeProps` maybe, and so on.

Typescript can also infer this correctly if you use the `as const` keyword:

```
const props = { tag: "a" } as const;
```

Typescript will understand that this `props` variable is a `CeProps<"a">` value. (Actually, technically, it will understand it as a `{ tag: "a"; }` type, but that is compatible with `CeProps<"a">` and can be passed to a function expecting that, for example.)

Finally, if you are interested in writing a function that can only take `CeProps` for particular tags, but not just *one* tag, you can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), which is indicated with a `|`:

```
function takesBoldOrItalics(props: CeProps<"b" | "i">): void {
```

You could call this function with `const aBold: CeProps<"b"> = { tag: "b" };`, or with `const anItalic = { tag: "i" } as const;`, or just call it directly like `takesBoldOrItalics({ tag: "b" });`. But if you try to call it with `{ tag: "a" }` you’ll get an error.

#### Constraining things to `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`

Another powerful tool in `lib.dom.d.ts` is `HTMLElementTagNameMap`, which gives the specific `HTMLElement` for each possible HTML tag string. It looks like this:

```
interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    "a": HTMLAnchorElement;
    "abbr": HTMLElement;
    "address": HTMLElement;
    "applet": HTMLAppletElement;
    "area": HTMLAreaElement;
    // ...
}
```

(Copied from `lib.dom.d.ts`)

This is used by `lib.dom.d.ts` to type `createElement` itself, for example:

```
createElement<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
    tagName: K,
    options?: ElementCreationOptions,
): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K];
```

(I copied this from `lib.dom.d.ts` and added some line breaks for readability.)

Notice the `<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>` part here. As with our `<Tag extends string>` on `CeProps`, this indicates a type parameter `K` with a constraint. So `K` must be some kind of `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`. If you are unfamiliar, `keyof` indicates the “keys of” some type—the property names. So `keyof { foo: number; bar: number; }` is `"foo" | "bar"`. And `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap` is `"a" | "abbr" | "address" | "applet" | "area" | ...`—a union of all of the potential HTML tag names (at least as of the last update to `lib.dom.d.ts`). That means `createElement` is requiring `tag` to be one of those strings (there are other overloads for it that handle other strings and just returns an `HTMLElement`).

We can leverage this same functionality in our `CeProps`:

```
type CeProps<Tag extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap = keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> =
    & {
        tag: Tag;
        style?: CSSStyleDeclaration;
        children?: CeProps[];
    }
    & {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
```

Now if we wrote `ce({ tag: "image" })` instead of `ce({ tag: "img" })` we would get an error instead of it being silently accepted and then not working correctly.

#### Typing the rest correctly

If we use `Tag extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`, we can type the “rest” properties more precisely, which protects you from making mistakes as well as limits the amount of casting you need to do inside `ce`.

To use it, I’ve updated `CeProps` like this:

```
interface MinimalCeProps<Tag extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> {
    tag: Tag;
    style?: CSSStyleDeclaration;
    children?: CeProps[];
}
type CeProps<Tag extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap = keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> =
    & MinimalCeProps<Tag>
    & Partial<Omit<HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag], keyof MinimalCeProps<Tag>>>;
```

I split it up into two parts, `MinimalCeProps` for the parts you want to always appear, and then the full `CeProps` which produces the intersection of that type with `Partial<Omit<HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag], keyof MinimalCeProps<Tag>>>`. That’s a mouthful, but we’ll break it down in a moment.

Now then, we have that business with `Partial` and `Omit`. To break it down,

- `HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag]` is the HTML element corresponding to `Tag`. You’ll notice this is the same type used as the return type on `createElement`.
- `Omit` indicates that we are leaving out some properties of the type we pass in as the first parameter, as indicated by the union of string literals in the second. For example, `Omit<{ foo: string; bar: number; baz: 42[]; }, "foo" | "bar">` will result in `{ bar: 42[]; }`.

  In our case, `Omit<HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag], keyof MinimalCeProps<Tag>>`, we are leaving out the properties from `HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag]` that are already properties in `MinimalCeProps<Tag>`—namely, `tag`, `style`, and `children`. This is important because `HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag]` is going to have some `children` property—and it’s not going to be `CeProps[]`. We could just use `Omit<HTMLElementTagNameMap[Tag], "children">` but I thought it best to be thorough—we want `MinimalCeProps` to “win” for all those tags.
- `Partial` indicates that all of the passed type’s properties should be made optional. So `Partial<{ foo: number; bar: string; baz: 42[]; }>` will be `{ foo?: number; bar?: string; baz?: 42[]; }`.

  In our case, this is just to indicate that we aren’t going to pass in *every* property of whatever HTML element here—just the ones we’re interested in overriding.

There are two advantages to doing things this way. First of all, this prevents typo’d or mis-typed properties from being added to the `CeProps`. Second, it can be leveraged by `ce` itself to reduce the reliance on casting:

```
function ce<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
    { tag, children, style, ...rest }: CeProps<T>,
): HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] {
    const element = window.document.createElement(tag);

    //Adding properties
    const otherProps = rest as unknown as Partial<HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]>;
    for (const prop in otherProps) {
        element[prop] = otherProps[prop]!;
    }

    //Adding children
    if (children) {
        for (const child of children) {
            element.appendChild(ce(child));
        }
    }

    //Adding styles
    if (style) {
        for (const prop in style) {
            element.style[prop] = style[prop];
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

Here, `element` automatically gets the correct type, `HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]` thanks to `createElement`’s type declaration. Then we have to create the `otherProps` “dummy variable,” and sadly that requires some casting—but we can be safer than casting to `any`. We also need to use `!` on `otherProps[prop]`—the `!` tells Typescript that the value isn’t `undefined`. This is because you could create a `CeProps` with an explicitly `undefined` value, like `{ class: undefined }`. Since that would be a weird mistake to make, it doesn’t seem worth checking against it. Properties you just leave out won’t be a problem, because they won’t appear in `for (const props in otherProps)`.

And more importantly, the return type of `ce` is correctly typed—just the same way that `createElement` is typed. This means that if you do `ce({ tag: "a" })`, Typescript will know you’re getting an `HTMLAnchorElement`.

#### Conclusion: Some examples/test cases

```
// Literal
ce({
    tag: "a",
    href: "test",
}); // HTMLAnchorElement

// Assigned to a variable without as const
const variable = {
    tag: "a",
    href: "test",
};
ce(variable); // Argument of type '{ tag: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CeProps<...

// Assigned to a variable using as const
const asConst = {
    tag: "a",
    href: "test",
} as const;
ce(asConst); // HTMLAnchorElement

// Giving invalid href property
ce({
    tag: "a",
    href: 42,
}); // 'number' is not assignable to 'string | undefined'

// Giving invalid property
ce({
    tag: "a",
    invalid: "foo",
}); // Argument of type '{ tag: "a"; invalid: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CeProps<"a">'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'invalid' does not exist in type 'CeProps<"a">'.
//   Did you mean to write 'oninvalid'?

// Giving invalid tag
ce({ tag: "foo" }); // Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"object" | "link" | "small" | ...
```

Comment: Does your `ElementByTag` definition have some advantage over, say, `type ElementByTag<T extends string> = T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[T] : HTMLElement;`?  Any time you have a bunch of string literals and you are checking against them with nested conditional types you could probably refactor as a lookup into some interface/type with those literals as keys (e.g., `K extends "foo" ? Foo : K extends "bar" ? Bar : ...` becomes `K extends keyof KeyMap ? KeyMap[K] : ..` with `interface KeyMap {foo: Foo, bar: Bar, ...}`.

Comment: @jcalz Likely no, I just didn’t know about `HTMLElementTagNameMap`. I’ll look into that when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz Turns out our project has a wildly out-of-date `lib.dom.d.ts` file attached to it. Hasn’t really been relevant to us (we don’t manipulate the DOM with native functions... ever?), but obviously messed with this answer. And for whatever reason, conditional logic is my first thought with cases like this—clearly it should be maps, given the recursion issue. Anyway, updated with a vastly improved version, thank you for that.